# Pass original URL through after login redirect

Tags: redirect

My WordPress site is setup so that all visitors have to login to view any page or post.

I have a redirection setup so that after a user with the role of **'reader'** log in they are redirected to a page called http:/www.example.com/readersetup

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if( $user->has_cap( 'reader' ) ) {
            $url = home_url('/readersetup');
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

This is working well, now what I would like to do is pass through a URL to the /readersetup page as a variable so that if somebody follows this...

- User goes to **www.example.com/mypost**
- Site redirects them to **www.example.com/wp-login.php**
- User Logs In and is redirect to **www.example.com/readersetup**
- **www.example.com/mypost** is saved as a variable and is available on **www.example.com/readersetup**

Whats the best way of achieving it?

Comment: You could pass the URL as a 'GET' variable, but you'd have to be careful to escape the URL correctly. My preference (not necessarily the best idea) is to pass the MIME-encode of the URL as a GET variable, so you don't have to worry about proper escaping.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?